# Kinvey query elements by date

Tags: javascript, date, time, querying, kinvey

I am trying ti query some elements from a Kinvey database in a specific time frame. I have the time of creation of the table row in Date ISO string **(_kmd.lmt)**: [_kmd.lmt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5x26.png)

I also got my **Date from** and **Date To** as Date ISO strings. Does anyone know how could I query the collection in order to get only the entities in the given time frame?

Comment: Don't post images, especially not links to images. Post information as text in your question, along with what you've tried and examples of the result you want (e.g. in this case, examples of dates that should and shouldn't match). See [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the records in a specific timeframe using "$gte" (greater than or equal to) and "$lte" (less than or equal to) on '_kmd.lmt' values ("kmd" means Kinvey Meta Data and "lmt" means Last Modified Time).

Let's say, you have following timestamps and you want to get all the records modified between those 2 timestamps:

**2018-02-19T06:42:36.862Z** - Mon, 19 Feb 2018 06:42:36 +00:00

**2018-07-13T04:28:38.479Z** - Fri, 13 Jul 2018 04:28:38 +00:00

Now you want to get all the records modified between above 2 timestamps i.e. **modified after 19th Feb and before 13th July**. Your query in the Kinvey API console should be:

/appdata/kid_xxx/Book/?query={"$and":[{"_kmd.lmt":{"$gte": "2018-02-19T06:42:36.862Z"}}, {"_kmd.lmt":{"$lt": "2018-07-13T04:28:38.479Z"}}]}

Thanks,

Pranav @Kinvey

Comment: Glad to help :)